# Magnific Popup showing same item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, magnific-popup

Refering to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151953/magnific-popup-showing-first-item-only) , it has a helpful answer but it's partial answer because it only shows three unique popup dialogs - static.

I'm new to jQuery and working in this project. I want this to be dynamic with MySql database. Let's say I have a collection of 20 products stored in a tbl_products and each product has a uniqe id, name and price. When user clicks for more product details, I want to display the Magnific popup dialog that shows the product details, showing the product image(small thumbnail), product name and product price.

This link is inside loop:

`<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog" data-item="<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">Open with fade-zoom animation</a><br>`

Here is the Code:

```
<div class="page-content">
    
        <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY product_id ASC LIMIT 20";
                        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                        $ctr = 0;
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    $i = 0;
                    $param = 'right';
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        //echo "<h2>" . $row[0] . "</h2>";
                        $data = $row["product_image"];
                        $images = explode(";", $data);
                        if($param=='left'){
                            $param = "right";
                        }
                        else{
                            $param = "left";
                            ?><div class="clear"></div><?php
                        }
                        
                        ?>
                        <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog" data-item="<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>">Open with fade-zoom animation</a><br>

                            <div id="small-dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
                            <span class="fa fa-check fa-3x" style="color: black; margin-left:45%;"></span>
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;">Artikulli u shtua në shportë</h3>
                                
                                <div class="table-responsive" style="border: none !important;">
                                            <table style="border: none !important;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th width="80%"></th>
                                                    <th width="20%"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-size:12px;">
                                                    
                                                        <div class="news-thumbs" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:20px;">
                                                            <a href="#" class="news-item">
                                                                <div style="line-height: 0.5cm;border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:5px; width:100%; height:110px; border-radius: 10px;  overflow: hidden; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
                                                                <amp-img class="responsive-img" src="../../../../../images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" width="100" height="100" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                                                                <h5><?php echo $row[1];?></h5>
                                                                <p style "font-size:11px;"> 
                                                                    <?php
                                                                        foreach(range(1, $row[10]) as $i)
                                                                        {
                                                                            ?>
                                                                                <span class="fa fa-star checked" style="color: #ffa500;"></span>
                                                                            <?php
                                                                        }
                                                                    ?>
                                                                </p>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    
                                                    <td style="margin-left:-50px; font-size:28px; font-style:bold; line-height:20px;">€<?php echo $row[2];?> <br>
                                                        <p style="font-size:11px; font-style:bold;">TVSH - 8% </p>
                                                        <p style="font-size:10px; line-height:20px;">Dërgesa Falas</p>
                                                        <a href="m-detail-<?php echo $row[0]; ?>.html" style="font-size:11px; line-height:20px;"> Shiko detalet</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:12px;"> </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <hr style="border-top: 0.5px solid #E8E8FF;">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default popup-modal-dismiss">Vazhdo me blerje</button>
                                    <button type="button" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-primary">Kryje porosinë</button>
                                 <!-- </div>
                                <div class="news-thumbs" style="margin-left:-50px;">
                                    <a href="#" class="news-item">
                                        <div style="line-height: 0.5cm;border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:5px; width:100%; height:110px; border-radius: 10px;  overflow: hidden; box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
                                        <amp-img class="responsive-img" src="../../../../../images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" width="100" height="100" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
                                        <h5><?php echo $row[1];?></h5>
                                        <p><?php echo $row[2];?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <hr style="border-top: 0.5px solid #E8E8FF;">
                                </div> -->
                                
                            </div>
                        
                        <a href="m-detail-<?php echo $row[0]; ?>.html">
                            <div class="half-material-box-<?php echo $param; ?>">
                            <span class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"style="color: red; aria-hidden="false";></span>
                                <!--<i class="center-text full-bottom huge-icon color-yellow-dark fa fa-bolt"></i>-->
                                <amp-img src="../../../../../images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" layout="responsive" width="127" height="130"></amp-img>
                                <p class="center-text small-text half-bottom">
                                    
                                    <!--<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><?php echo substr_replace($row[1], "...", 60);?>-->
                                </p>
                                <h3 class="small-text lef-text bold" name="hidden_name" style="color:#969696;"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></h3>
                                <h4 class="left-text thick" name="hidden_price" style="color:#f94b2b;">€ <?php echo $row[2]; ?></h4>
                                
                                <?php
                                    foreach(range(1, $row[10]) as $i)
                                    {
                                        //echo $i; 
                                        ?>
                                            <span class="fa fa-star checked" style="color: #ffa500;"></span>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                <!--    </form> -->
                        <?php
                    
                    }
                }
        ?>
        
        <div class="clear"></div>
        
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".popup-with-zoom-anim").each(function() {
            $(this).magnificPopup({

                  type: 'inline',
                 fixedBgPos: true,
                
                 fixedContentPos: true,
                 overflowY: 'hidden',

                 closeBtnInside: false,
                 preloader: false,
                
                 midClick: true,
                 removalDelay: 300,
                 mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'  
            });

        });
        $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            }); 

      });
})(jQuery);
```

It shows the Popup dialog the way I want but the problem is that it shows the same data no matter what product I click!

I can't figure it out weather it has problem with Id or .each instance in jQuery. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have elements with a fixed `id` inside a loop? That’s a sure-fire way to create invalid HTML. It would be absolutely no surprise that JS doesn’t work as intended.

Comment: @SebastianSimon 'data-item="<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>" ' am I supossed to use id instead of data-item?

Comment: What…? No, I’m talking about `<div id="small-dialog">` and the reference to it via `<a href="#small-dialog">`. That’s inside the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` loop. [Validate your HTML](//validator.nu) (the rendered HTML, not the PHP).

Comment: But each product must have the link href="#small-dialog" to show Popup dialog. That's why it's inside while loop. Do you know how to make these elements with a dynamic 'id'?

Comment: Then introduce a counter and append it to the `id` and the `href` attribute values. The important thing is that they’re unique.

Comment: But the ' href="#small-dialog" ' is the id reference in .css file of Magnific style.css
<a id="<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>" class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog">Open with fade-zoom animation</a> do you mean like this?

Comment: Similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236287/changing-id-small-dialog-name-in-magnificent-popup